# Java Binary tree insert is not working properly

Tags: java, recursion, insert, binary-tree, nodes

When i add a node for example, named "Bob" in the insert method:

```
public void insert(String aLabel){
    //left recursion:
    if(this.getLabel().compareTo(aLabel) <= 0) {
        if (childrenLeft == null) {
            BSTreeNode aNode = new  BSTreeNode(aLabel,this);
            return;
        }
    else {
            childrenLeft.insert(aLabel);
        }
    }
    //right recursion
    else {
        if (childrenRight==null) {
            BSTreeNode aNode = new BSTreeNode(aLabel,this);
            return;
        }
    else{
            childrenRight.insert(aLabel);
        }

    }

}
```

my tree only adds a blank node with no label on the left side of the treee only. is there something wrong with the (BSTreeNode aNode = new BSTreeNode;)? because when i hard code the nodes like:

```
BSTreeNode Louis = new BSTreeNode("Louis", treeRoot);
BSTreeNode bonny = new BSTreeNode( "bonny", treeRoot);
BSTreeNode Sue = new BSTreeNode("Anne", bonny);
BSTreeNode Sam = new BSTreeNode("Sam",Louis);
BSTreeNode Anne2 = new BSTreeNode( "delta", bonny);
BSTreeNode Frank = new BSTreeNode("Kalle", Louis);
```

the tree shows both a label and is inserted at the desired location. 
other code-
the constructor:

```
public BSTreeNode( String aLabel,BSTreeNode aParent){
    label = aLabel;
    parent = aParent;
 //add this node as a child of this node's parent either left or right

    if(parent != null){
        if(parent.getLabel().compareTo(label)<= 0) {
            parent.addLeftChild(this);
        }
        if(parent.getLabel().compareTo(label)> 0) {
            parent.addRightChild(this);
        }

    }

}
```

this is the constructor that adds the node to the parent when a node is created.
add childleft and right methods:

```
private void addLeftChild(BSTreeNode aNode){
    if(childrenLeft == null) this.childrenLeft = aNode;

}
private void addRightChild(BSTreeNode aNode) {
    if(childrenRight == null) this.childrenRight = aNode;

}
```

Comment: I don't see insert() called in the other two code blocks.

Comment: Could you add the code for the class BSTreeNode

Comment: those codes were added to show that the constructor is still able to work without the insert as long as the nodes are hard coded in the main App. it basically shows how the constructor works which is also used to make a new Node in the insert method.

Comment: adding the whole class(tons of code) would be impractical, still the insert method works independent of other methods created within the BSTreeNode class. with exception of the constructor itself.

Comment: Have you tried to do step by step debugging in an IDE & check the variable values during execution. Might be a faster way to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Have a look at your logic. When creating new BSTreeNodes, the function goes into the constructor -> then goes into addLeftChild/addRightChild. Checks if it's null and if yes, it adds it. What happens if it's not null? Your insert function takes care of this but your constructor does not. And from your code, you're calling the constructor. Try running with those checks in place and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most binary trees follow a different style, and set the parent's left/right child inside the recursive method, instead of the child going up and telling somebody it's their new parent

This code is a bit more standard for how most binary trees function:

```
public void insert(String aLabel)
{
    if(getLabel().compareTo(aLabel) <= 0)
        if(childrenLeft == null)
            childrenLeft = new BSTreeNode(aLabel, this);
        else
            childrenLeft.insert(aLabel);
    else
        if(childrenRight == null)
            childrenRight = new BSTreeNode(aLabel, this);
        else
            childrenRight.insert(aLabel);
}
```

That code should correctly save the values of the BSTreeNodes being created, and has the added effect of being less confusing as to how a parent is getting it's child

It makes a whole lot more sense to most people for a parent to be getting a child, instead of a child reaching up to a node and telling it that it's the new child on the block

Answer (score 0):

You logic might be a little flawed.

When adding from your constructor, you're calling `addLeftChild` or `addRightChild` directly. These function check if the node on the right/left is `null` or not and adds the value if its null. But what if it's not null. It should then compare to the left/right child and continue because otherwise the nodes do not get added (i.e. the function falls through & doesn't return anything as its `void`).